# How to empty bookmarklist of selected rows (delphi)

Tags: delphi

I use this code for multi selecting rows in dataset. It works fine but if I execute it second, third etc time new rows are added to last rows. How empty bookmarklist of last selected rows?

```
var
sql: string;
i:integer;
     
query1.close;
query1.open;
query1.Filtered:=false;
for i := 0 to dbgrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 Do Begin
  dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(dbgrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);
  s:=s+','+inttostr(dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
end;
delete(s,1,1);
sql:='ID in('+s+')';
query1.Filter:= sql;
query1.Filtered:=true;
frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))))+'\FastReports\Labels_DocOut_id.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

I tried:

```
query1.close; query1.open;

DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := false;

dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.delete;

DBGrid1.SelectedRows.clear;

DBGrid1.SelectedRows.delete;
```

but without success.

Comment: You need to clear variable `s` for new execution.

Comment: Do what @AminAlinezhad says, at the beginning of the function. Local vars don't get initialized, you have to do it yourself!

Comment: @AminAlinezhad, Delphi Coder as I found out I forgot to declare local variable `s` but there ara global variable `s` in project and instead it was used. :)  Thank you!